# the click on chrome extension icon doesn't trigger chrome.browserAction.onClicked each time I clicked the icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to detect every time a user clicks the extension icon.
I used `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){console.log('icon clicked')})` but I get the message one time only, when I click second time, third time, ... I get nothing. I don't know where is the problem

Below a portions of code of the extension:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My ext",
    "version": "0.1",
    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "My ext"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }   }
```

`background.js`

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
   console.log("icon clicked")
   // do something
});
```

Comment: That code should work fine. Are you sure identical logs aren't just getting collapsed? If you try `console.log("icon clicked at " + new Date().getTime())` instead, do you still see only one log entry after multiple clicks?

Comment: @jgaul I found the problem, the problem is that I use `chrome.browserAction.setPopup` after `console.log`, now it work without `setPopup`. But I need to use it after do a check, any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain the desired behavior in greater detail and provide the code for reproducing the issue? Also, to check, do you have multiple popups you want to use, such that statically configuring something like `"browser_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html"}` in your manifest as shown [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) won't suffice?

Comment: @jgaul I want each time a user click the extension icon check if he is logged in or not, and depend on his status I will set a popup.

Comment: So to check my understanding, when the user clicks the icon, you want to only show them a popup if they have a certain login status?

Comment: Make sure you've enabled timestamps in devtools settings, otherwise it only bumps the duplicates counter before the last message.

Comment: @jgaul if a user is logged in I will set `main.html` popup, else (if the user isn't logged in) I will set different popup let's say `popup.html`.

Comment: OK, given that the [`setPopup` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup) says that this function `Sets the html document to be opened as a popup when the user clicks on the browser action's icon`, it doesn't sound like it's meant to be used in response to a user clicking the icon. Rather, it seems that you should use it to set the desired popup _before_ the user clicks the icon, perhaps in response to some login event or check.

Comment: @jgaul thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck.